# How to pass a variable to a Twig Filter

Tags: php, twig

How can I pass a variable into a Twig filter to achieve something like this:

`<img src="{{ post.thumbnail.src|resize(thumbsize) }}" />`

Here the `thumbsize` would be the variable I would be passing to the filter, is this possible?

Comment: You want to create your own filter? [How to extend twig](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html)

Comment: This filter is already provided by Timber for Wordpress, what I need in this case is just to pass that `thumbsize` as a variable available in twig.
As it is on my sample code above doesn't seem to work.

Comment: U need to define the variable `thumbsize` or pass a static value like : `{{ foo.src|resize(150) }}`

Comment: Thank you @DarkBee, I do have thumbsize available as a var, it does output `320,240` with `{{thumbsize}}` but inside the filter doesn't work as expected. If I pass `320,240` directly as static value to the filter it does work.

Comment: I see. This mean the filter expects 2 arguments while thumbsize is treated as one string. You could change the `thumbsize` var to an array to make it dynamic

Comment: Thank you so much @DarkBee, can you add that as reply so I can mark the issue resolved and give you the SO karma? ;)

For reference, I had to access the array values like this:
```<img src="{{ post.thumbnail.src|resize(thumbsize[0],thumbsize[1]) }}" />```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your PHP file you'll need to define `thumbsize` and give it a value:

#### This example is to set just the width and have the height scale:

`$context = Timber::get_context();
$context['thumbsize'] = 300;
Timber::render('my-template.twig', $context);`

Then in twig:
`<img src="{{ post.thumbnail.src|resize(thumbsize) }}" />`

#### This example is to set values for both width and height

`$context = Timber::get_context();
$context['thumbsize'] = array('width' => 600, 'height' => 400);
Timber::render('my-template.twig', $context);`

Then in twig:
`<img src="{{ post.thumbnail.src|resize(thumbsize.width, thumbsize.height) }}" />`

Answer (score 1):

Its seem the filter `resize` expects 2 parameters to work (see comments).
Currently the var `thumbsize` was passed like a string and therefore treated as one argument.

You could change the var `thumbsize` from string to an array and then pass it like :

```
{{ post.thumbnail.src|resize(thumbsize[0],thumbsize[1]) }}
```